# How to scrape BTC volume from yahoo finance with requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to get BTC volume data by using `beautifulsoup` from https://finance.yahoo.com

source of yahoo finance

```
<tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Volume</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="TD_VOLUME-value"><fin-streamer data-symbol="BTC-USD" data-field="regularMarketVolume" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="2" data-dfield="longFmt" value="12,728,260,608" active="">12,728,260,608</fin-streamer></td></tr>

<tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Volume (24hr)</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="TD_VOLUME_24HR-value">12.73B</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) Bdbw(0)! "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Volume (24hr) All Currencies</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="TD_VOLUME_24HR_ALLCURRENCY-value">12.73B</td></tr>
```

I'm trying something like that

```
url1v = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD"
page1v = requests.get(url1v)
html_page1v = BeautifulSoup(page1v.content, "html.parser")

btc_volume = html_page1v.find("span", {"class":"e3b14781 dde7f18a"})
print(btc_volume)
```

> output: none

how should I write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First at all and always check your `response` / `soup`, what is not in you will not find.*

It needs an [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) otherwise the correct content would be blocked or not provided by the server.

##### Example

The user agent in the example is fictitious (guess the movie), as the content itself does not seem to be checked - Check [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) for further information:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url,headers={'user-agent':'Tom Bishop ;)'}).text)
soup.select_one('[data-field="regularMarketVolume"]').text
```

##### Output

```
12,394,450,944
```